# Add ToolTip to DataGridTextColumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tooltip

I am building a WPF MVVM application with a `DataGrid`, whose `ItemsControl` is a `DataTable`.

I have an autogenerated column, let's call it `First`.

**How I am populating it in the ViewModel:**

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("FirstDataTable");
dataTable.Columns.Add("First", typeof(string));

foreach (Model item in modelItems)
{
      DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

      dataRow[0] = $"{item.SomeValues.First().Name}"; //could also be just item.SomeValues (for the sake of binding it somehow)

      dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

**Model.cs:**

```
public class Model
{
      public ObservableCollection<SubModel> SomeValues { get; set; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<SubModel>
        {
            new SubModel("first try", 1),
            new SubModel("second try", 2)
        };
}
```

**SubModel.cs:**

```
public class SubModel
{
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public double Value { get; set; }
    
       public SubModel(string name, double value)
       {
             Name = name;
             Value = value;
       }
}
```

**AutoGeneratingColumn:**

```
var textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn
{
       Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName),
       Header = e.PropertyName,
       CellStyle = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("FirstColumnStyle") as Style
};

e.Column = textColumn;
```

**xaml of the page:**

```
<Style x:Key="FirstColumnStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
     //some setter`enter code here`s
     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ???}" />
</Style>
```

What I am currently doing is displaying the first `Model`'s name (so "first try") in the DataGridTextColumn `First`.

What I want to do is when I hover over "first try" a tooltip to be displayed with all the `Value`s from `SomeValues` (so basically "first try" on one line, and "second try" on another line).

Is it possible to bind it? And if so, what is the best way to achieve that?

PS: I thought about using a DataGridComboBoxColumn/DataGridTemplateColumn with a ComboBox, but couldn't figure out how to bind it, as as far as I understood, ComboBox can only bind to a StaticResource or a property in the ViewModel, which is not my case.

> To populate the drop-down list, first set the ItemsSource property for the ComboBox by using one of the following options:
>
> > A static resource. For more information, see StaticResource Markup Extension.

> > An x:Static code entity. For more information, see x:Static Markup Extension.

> > An inline collection of ComboBoxItem types.

**What I have managed to achieve:**

I tried binding to the `ViewModel` (which is not what I want, but still).

Created a string property `Test` in the `ViewModel`.

Added in the `Grid.Resources`:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="TestKey" Value="{Binding Test}" />
```

aand in the `Style`:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource TestKey}}" />
```

This works, but it's still not what I want.

Comment: do you need to use DataTable ?

Comment: It is not a requirement, no, but I have 6+ other columns and I figured that it might be the best approach. (I am autogenerating them as well and have omitted them in the question for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: If you have constant amount of columns for your case, you can rather add columns manually to datagrid and set tooltip for each column. If not, you may consider adding columns dynamically

Comment: I am adding them dynamically in an AutoGeneratingColumn event. The amount of columns may increase during runtime.

Comment: Then, you can handle AutoGeneratingColumn event to set tooltips there?

Comment: Correct, I just don't know how to do the binding, I will update my question with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your approach, I have another solution, it will look like this;

[image]

You may use a custom structure to get this behavior:

**Demo usage**

```
public class MainViewModel
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CreateDemoTable();
    }

    public CustomTable MyTable { get; set; }


    private void CreateDemoTable()
    {
        MyTable = new CustomTable("MyTable");

        string propertyName1 = "Prop1";
        MyTable.AddColumn(propertyName1, "Tool Tip 1");

        string propertyName2 = "Prop2";
        MyTable.AddColumn(propertyName2, "Tool Tip 2");



        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GenericRow row = new GenericRow();

            row.AddProperty<string>(propertyName1);
            row.SetPropertyValue(propertyName1, "Test Value 1");


            row.AddProperty<string>(propertyName2);
            row.SetPropertyValue(propertyName2, "Test Value 2");

            MyTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="dataGrid"
        local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding MyTable.Columns}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable.Rows}" />

</Grid>
```

**All you need:**

**DataGridColumnsBehavior**

```
  public class DataGridColumnsBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                                typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                                typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
        private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
            ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
            dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
            if (columns == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
            {
                NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
                if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
                }
            };
        }
        public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
        {
            element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
        }
        public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
        }
    }
```

**Generic Row**

```
public class GenericRow : CustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Private Fields
    List<PropertyDescriptor> _property_list = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChange Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChange Implementation

    #region Public Methods

    public void SetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName, T propertyValue)
    {
        var properties = this.GetProperties()
                                .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                .Where(prop => prop.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        if (properties == null || properties.Count() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("The property doesn't exist.");
        }

        var property = properties.First();
        property.SetValue(this, propertyValue);

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public T GetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var properties = this.GetProperties()
                            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                            .Where(prop => prop.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        if (properties == null || properties.Count() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("The property doesn't exist.");
        }

        var property = properties.First();
        return (T)property.GetValue(this);
    }

    public void AddProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var customProperty = new CustomPropertyDescriptor<T>(propertyName, typeof(GenericRow));

        _property_list.Add(customProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overriden Methods

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
                            properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                      .Concat(_property_list).ToArray());
    }

    #endregion

}

public class CustomPropertyDescriptor<T> : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private Type propertyType;
    private Type componentType;
    T propertyValue;

    public CustomPropertyDescriptor(string propertyName, Type componentType)
        : base(propertyName, new Attribute[] { })
    {
        this.propertyType = typeof(T);
        this.componentType = componentType;
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return true; }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return componentType; } }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return propertyValue;
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return propertyType; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { SetValue(component, default(T)); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        if (!value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Invalid type to assign");
        }

        propertyValue = (T)value;
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return true; }
}
```

**Custom table**

```
public class CustomTable
{
    public ObservableCollection<GenericRow> Rows { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GenericRow>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public CustomTable(string tableName)
    {
        this.TableName = tableName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ColumnName is also binding property name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName"></param>
    public void AddColumn(string columnName, string toolTip)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();

        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.ToolTip = toolTip;
        textBlock.Text = columnName;

        column.Header = textBlock;
        column.Binding = new Binding(columnName);

        Columns.Add(column);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TableName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! What are the benefits of this custom structure to the normal DataTable?

Comment: Upper defined GenericRow is similar to DataTable, the good side is actually custom columns. You can define custom columns and added them to datagrid.